# General Extreme Value Distribution that is closed under both Minimum and Maximum

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am wondering if there is an extreme value distribution that is closed under both the minimum and the maximum operation.
For example, for there is a Gumbel maximum distribution closed under the maximum (provided $\beta$ is the same for both distributions). Also there is the Gumbel minimum distribution closed under minimum. However, I am interested in a distribution that is closed under both such that, given two distributions $X_1,X_2$, I can find $Y_1=\min(X_1,X_2)$ and $Y_2=\max(X_1,X_2)$, which are of the same kind of distribution.
If it only holds in special cases (except the trivial case if iid) that would also be interesting.

I imagine that it is possible that no such kind of distribution exists, in which case my question is why this does not exist / if there is a proof that it cannot exist.

Thank you.
Felix

Comment: Let's invent a family, and call it the "polynomial distributions on $[0,1]$" where the density and CDF of each is polynomial and meets the standard requirements.  Then the minimum and maximum distributions are also polynomial distributions on $[0,1]$

Comment: Thanks, I understand. I should have clarified that I was looking for an unbounded distribution parameterized via a (scalar) location and a (scalar) scale.